# Turn json value into var

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to format a read item from a DB to a simple var (node.js 6.10).
**My ambition is to have a "var Value" which contains the read value (487).**

**This is the code now:**

```
{     
 console.log("Success", data.Item);
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}
```

**This is the output:**

> Success { Value: { N: '487' } }
>
> { "Item": { "Value": { "N": "487" }   } }

How can I solve this in a better way as stringify didnt work as I hoped?

Comment: What is the desired output? `{ "Data" : 487 }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Value = data.Item.Value.N
console.log(Value)
// outputs: '487'
```

Comment: @martik If you are not in control of the original Json object it is safer to add if checks around the presence of each of the sub-objects.You could create a function like `const Value = safeAccess("Item.Value.N", data)`